# CNN Model Definition input and output change with RGB

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am trying to a traffic sign dataset using a CNN, i have done it was a grayscale conversion but want to see the affect of using RGB. I am using a size of 32x32x1 but this will now be 32x32x3.

```
class ConvNet(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super(ConvNet, self).__init__() 
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1,
                           out_channels=6,
                           kernel_size=(5,5),
                           stride=(1,1))
    self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size = (2,2))
    self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d (in_channels=6,
                            out_channels=16,
                            kernel_size=(5,5),
                            stride=(1,1))
    self.pool4 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2,2))
    self.conv5 = nn.Conv2d (in_channels=16,
                           out_channels=120,
                           kernel_size=(5,5),
                           stride=(1,1))
    self.fc6 = nn.Linear(in_features=120,
                         out_features=84)
    self.fc7 = nn.Linear(in_features=84,
                         out_features=62)
def forward(self,x):
    x = x.view([-1, 1, 32, 32])
    x = nn.functional.relu(self.conv1(x))
    x = self.pool2(x)
    x = nn.functional.relu(self.conv3(x))
    x = self.pool4(x)
    x = nn.functional.relu(self.conv5(x))
    x = x.view(-1, 120)
    x = nn.functional.relu(self.fc6(x))
    x = self.fc7(x)
    return x
```

What I cant understand how to do is the definition of the layers with the additional channels. Would appreciate help in defining this.

Comment: Change the input channels in first conv layer to 3.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only changing the channels for only the input layer, you only need to change `self.conv1`'s input channels to 3, instead of 1: `self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=6, kernel_size=(5,5), stride=(1,1))`. Doing this, you will also have to change your flattening shape `[-1, 1, 32, 32]` to `[-1, 3, 32, 32]` because you now have 3 channels.